# Xpath expression in R giving different result than the chrome inspector

Tags: r, xml, xpath, web-scraping, xml2

Using the xpath given below, to fetch the date content from various pages, I get the desired results. But this page specifically, "http://eventsgeneva.strikingly.com//blog/agenda-geneve-something-you-should-never-miss", is giving the desired result when using chrome inspector whereas using the same xpath in R gives no result.

---

While using below xpath in chrome.

```
xpath = '((//h1/parent::*/following::*|//h1/ancestor::*[position()<3]/descendant-or-self::*)[position()<150 and (string-length(text())<150 and (contains(text(), "Jan") or contains(text(), "Feb") or contains(text(), "Mar") or contains(text(), "Apr") or contains(text(), "May") or contains(text(), "Jun") or contains(text(), "Jul") or contains(text(), "Aug") or contains(text(), "Sep") or contains(text(), "Oct") or contains(text(), "Nov") or contains(text(), "Dec")))])'
```

I get,

[image]

While using the same xpath in R using library "xml2".

I get nodeset 0

```r
library(dplyr)

library(xml2)

html_page<-read_html("http://eventsgeneva.strikingly.com//blog/agenda-geneve-something-you-should-never-miss")

html_page%>%
  xml_find_all(xpath = '((//h1/parent::*/following::*|//h1/ancestor::*[position()<3]/descendant-or-self::*)[position()<150 and (string-length(text())<150 and (contains(text(), "Jan") or contains(text(), "Feb") or contains(text(), "Mar") or contains(text(), "Apr") or contains(text(), "May") or contains(text(), "Jun") or contains(text(), "Jul") or contains(text(), "Aug") or contains(text(), "Sep") or contains(text(), "Oct") or contains(text(), "Nov") or contains(text(), "Dec")))])')
#> {xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Anything I'm missing out on ?

Comment: Are you sure the contents you want to get isn't generated dynamically by JavaScript in chrome?

Comment: Not sure, seems like contents are not generated dynamically. Though I cannot find any desired string match "August 5, 2018" in the html text obtained via R.

Comment: Why do you think it's not generated dynamically, then?

Comment: Web pages are more like complicated applications now a days rather than simple text files. Most use javascript to load/change content after the page has loaded. Simple web scrapers cannot run the same javascript that your browser can. Maybe you need something like [RSelenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium) to execute the javascript for you.

Comment: Use "View Source" in chrome/firefox/safari. You'll see there are `<script>` tags. After the JS is loaded the content in one of the firt `<script>` tags and put into the visible DOM. Either fetch the `<script>` tag and process it or use [`splashr`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr), [`decapitated`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/decapitated) or legacy tools like selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extrapolation from the above content:

#### Using `decapitated`:

```
library(rvest)
library(decapitated)
library(tidyverse)

doc <- decapitated::chrome_read_html("http://eventsgeneva.strikingly.com//blog/agenda-geneve-something-you-should-never-miss")

html_nodes(doc, xpath = '((//h1/parent::*/following::*|//h1/ancestor::*[position()<3]/descendant-or-self::*)[position()<150 and (string-length(text())<150 and (contains(text(), "Jan") or contains(text(), "Feb") or contains(text(), "Mar") or contains(text(), "Apr") or contains(text(), "May") or contains(text(), "Jun") or contains(text(), "Jul") or contains(text(), "Aug") or contains(text(), "Sep") or contains(text(), "Oct") or contains(text(), "Nov") or contains(text(), "Dec")))])')
## {xml_nodeset (1)}
## [1] <span class="s-blog-date">August 4, 2018</span>
```

Please read the README and pkg docs as you need Chrome (preferably a separate Chromium binary as explained in the package) and an environment variable setup and you'll have to debug any setup issues on your own.

#### Using `splashr`

The `splashr` package requires the `reticulate` package, Docker and the Python `docker` module. So more self-debugging if you run into issues:

```
library(rvest)
library(splashr)
library(tidyverse)

sp <- splashr::start_splash()

doc <- render_html(splash_local, "http://eventsgeneva.strikingly.com//blog/agenda-geneve-something-you-should-never-miss")

html_nodes(doc, xpath = '((//h1/parent::*/following::*|//h1/ancestor::*[position()<3]/descendant-or-self::*)[position()<150 and (string-length(text())<150 and (contains(text(), "Jan") or contains(text(), "Feb") or contains(text(), "Mar") or contains(text(), "Apr") or contains(text(), "May") or contains(text(), "Jun") or contains(text(), "Jul") or contains(text(), "Aug") or contains(text(), "Sep") or contains(text(), "Oct") or contains(text(), "Nov") or contains(text(), "Dec")))])')
## {xml_nodeset (1)}
## [1] <span class="s-blog-date">August 4, 2018</span>

killall_splash()
```

#### Using `V8`

To avoid using external programs you can use `V8` to process the page variables and get to the content:

```
library(rvest)
library(V8)
library(tidyverse)

ctx <- v8()

doc <- read_html("http://eventsgeneva.strikingly.com//blog/agenda-geneve-something-you-should-never-miss")

html_nodes(doc, xpath=".//script")[[1]] %>% # get 1st <script>
  html_text() %>% # get contents of it
  str_replace(regex("^.*window\\.", multiline=TRUE), "var $S = {};\n") %>% # make the variable usable in V8
  ctx$eval() # evaluate the javascript
## [1] "[object Object]"

pg <- ctx$get("$S") # marshall it to R
```

It's a big structure so examine it methodically:

```
str(pg, 1)
## List of 6
##  $ globalConf        :List of 26
##  $ conf              :List of 12
##  $ miniProgramAppType: NULL
##  $ blogPostData      :List of 5
##  $ siteData          :List of 5
##  $ stores            :List of 3

str(pg$blogPostData, 1)
## List of 5
##  $ blogPostMeta:List of 25
##  $ pageMeta    :List of 33
##  $ content     :List of 8
##  $ settings    :List of 2
##  $ pageMode    : NULL

str(pg$blogPostData$content, 1)
## List of 8
##  $ type            : chr "Blog.BlogData"
##  $ id              : chr "f_cc4ace2d-21ed-4b94-83a0-e83497e5afc4"
##  $ defaultValue    : NULL
##  $ showComments    : logi TRUE
##  $ showShareButtons: NULL
##  $ header          :List of 6
##  $ footer          :List of 5
##  $ sections        :'data.frame':    9 obs. of  4 variables:
```

Content seems to be here:

```
str(pg$blogPostData$content$sections)
## 'data.frame':    9 obs. of  4 variables:
##  $ type        : chr  "Blog.Section" "Blog.Section" "Blog.Section" "Blog.Section" ...
##  $ id          : chr  "f_9ca5a1d7-ccb8-4315-9883-bcd43d271b9c" "f_4b7b30f1-387c-4cbe-aaed-ddaedea92cc1" "f_252813ac-b6cb-484b-81f5-64d7f0745c8e" "f_bd7412a4-b94b-4c5a-8cdd-a48931639dce" ...
##  $ defaultValue: logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
##  $ component   :'data.frame':    9 obs. of  6 variables:
##   ..$ type        : chr  "RichText" "RichText" "RichText" "RichText" ...
##   ..$ id          : chr  "f_4e41d6f3-8449-4f66-b701-28d1bcfb08c9" "f_c27703de-8679-4916-9697-220cb8c7a74d" "f_c3c20474-99fc-434a-aff1-102d2a342450" "f_7b3e5247-39ef-42c7-b95c-f0be0b6e9728" ...
##   ..$ defaultValue: logi  FALSE NA NA NA NA NA ...
##   ..$ value       : chr  "<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">We all make our plans beforehand in order to avoid any unnecessary issues. So"| __truncated__ "<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">Take a glance at the below-listed events and plan accordingly -</p>" "<p style=\"text-align: justify;\"><u>Siestes dominicales</u> – Here you are invited to groove on the grass and "| __truncated__ "<p style=\"text-align: justify;\"><u>Sonoboat ACT</u> – Neptune is one the most popular and historic sailing bo"| __truncated__ ...
##   ..$ backupValue : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
##   ..$ version     : int  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 1
```

Either evaluate `value` individually or `paste0()` them into a single HTML chunk and eval that.

As an aside, Strikingly has one of the daftest and low-content-integrity/safety publishing solutions I've seen in a while. I know you're just scraping it but I'd advise any folks considering using them to not use them.